# is it possible to install canvas with M1 chip

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run this command in MacBook Pro M1 to install canvas:

```
 npm install --save-dev canvas
```

shows error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.0/canvas-v2.9.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.0/canvas-v2.9.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.9.0 and node@16.13.2 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.0/canvas-v2.9.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.1 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:261:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.3.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

does anyone facing the same problem. what should I to to fix it or avoid this problem? The node version is 16.x. I have already tried to install `pkgconfig` like this:

```
brew install pkgconfig
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I finally found before install cavas in macOS, we need to install some dependencies using brew like this:

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
```

then run the install command again will success. more info from the official document: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas